Showing that $\int_0^1 \frac{\text{d}x}{\zeta(x)\Gamma(x)}<0<1<\int_0^\infty \frac{\text{d}x}{\zeta(x)\Gamma(x)}$ in $3$ minutes, without a calculator
The following question is to be solved within $3$ minutes, without a calculator.
$$\text{Let }I=\int_0^\infty \frac{\text{d}x}{\zeta(x)\Gamma(x)}\text{, and let }J=\int_0^1 \frac{\text{d}x}{\zeta(x)\Gamma(x)}\text{. Which of the following is true?}$$
$\text{(A) }0<J<I<1$
$\text{(B) }0<J<1<I$
$\text{(C) }J<0<I<1$
$\text{(D) }J<0<1<I$
$\text{(E) }0<I<J<1$

I could not estimate any of these two integrals. When I gave up, I used Wolfram Alpha and concluded that
$$\int_0^1 \frac{\text{d}x}{\zeta(x)\Gamma(x)}<0<1<\int_0^\infty \frac{\text{d}x}{\zeta(x)\Gamma(x)}$$
Hence $\text{(D)}$ is the correct option.

I am asking for hints and key ideas to estimate such integrals, not a detailed work.

Your help would be appreciated. THANKS!

Within three minutes ? I would need much more time to find a reasonable approach ...

@Peter The source (exam) of this problem has $75$ problems to be solved in $4$ hours. So, almost $3$ minutes per problem. However, some problems may take less than that, so this problem may take a bit longer than $3$ minutes, say $6$ minutes (max). And of course, exact values are not required to answer it, sufficient estimations lead to the correct answer.

$\zeta(x) < 0 < \Gamma(x)$ for $0<x<1$, so sign of $J$ is pretty obvious. The hardest part is $I$, I think. And value of $I$ is $1.06074857...$, so it requires very strong approximation, also I think.

Concluding that $J<0$ is trivial, since
$$
\zeta(x) < 0 \qquad \Gamma(x) > 0
$$
on $(0,1)$. What would remain, then, is showing that $I > 1$. Not sure on that (and just playing with some graphs, I'd be inclined to doubt it, even).

@PrincessEev Wow! You are right. With that, we have eliminated most of the options, and left with $\text{(C)}$ and $\text{(D)}$ only. Thanks for pointing this, which was not trivial for me.
